# Java RestEasy Client builder issue in Jboss EAP 7.1 upgrade

Tags: java, upgrade, resteasy, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-7

My application is getting upgraded to Jboss 6.2 to Jboss 7.1 and Java 7 to Java 8. So while doing deployment, We are facing below issue:

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving
>   overridden method
>   "org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.register(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Configurable;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of
>   the current class,
>   org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder, and its
>   superclass loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader),
>   have different Class objects for the type
>   javax/ws/rs/core/Configurable used in the signature

Could anybody help me .. Rest easy version.- 3.0.10 Final

Comment: I would suggest you to provide dependencies of your project. A pom file, for example. So we could see what libraries and which versions are being used.

Answer (score 0):

> Resteasy is bundled with JBoss AS 7. You will likely have the need to upgrade Resteasy in AS7. The Resteasy distribution comes with a zip file called resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.7.Final.zip. Unzip this file while with the modules/ directory of the JBoss AS7 distribution. This will overwrite some of the existing files there.

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#upgrading-as7

Are you trying to include rest easy in your WAR? If so, exclude it and just add dependency line in your project, and load it from JBOSS bundled module.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have excluded the Rest easy Jars which are in the JBOSS bundle. And we are adding the dependency in our pom file only.